# JButton change image and keep the size

Tags: java, image, jbutton, imageicon

Actually, I already know how to change the image in the button but the problem is with the size.

I changed for the new icon, but I want to preserve the size but this change please some advice with this.

I've tried to get the dimension of the button before change the image to set it then but the size doesn't cache, and it doesn't visually change.

Comment: Do you require the image to be scaled to fit the button, or the button to be resized?  The best advice would be to do neither, but instead distribute a set of icons with identical size.  BTW - Are the icons even the same aspect ratio?

Answer (score 3):

That's because the button uses an icon, which is a fixed size.  If you want to do this in Java, you'll have to

- `.getImage()` from your ImageIcon object or somewhere else
- Make a new `BufferedImage`
- Draw a scaled version of your image, into the `BufferedImage` (with the size you want)
- Make a new `ImageIcon` using the new image
- Send that `ImageIcon` to your button

The first three steps sound tricky, but they're not too bad.  Here's a method to get you started:

```
/**
 * Gets a scaled version of an image.
 * 
 * @param original0 original Image
 * @param w0 int new width
 * @param h0 int new height
 * @return {@link java.awt.Image}
 */
public Image getImage(Image original0, int w0, int h0) {
    // Check for sizes less than 1
    w0 = (w0 < 1) ? 1 : w0;
    h0 = (h0 < 1) ? 1 : h0;

    // The new scaled image (empty for now.)
    // Uses BufferedImage to support scaling and rendering.
    final BufferedImage scaled = new BufferedImage(w0, h0, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    // Create a canvas to draw with, in the new image.
    final Graphics2D g2d = scaled.createGraphics();

    // Try to prevent aliasing (if your image doesn't look good, read more about RenderingHints, they're not too hard)
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);

    // Use the canvas to draw the scaled version into the empty BufferedImage
    g2d.drawImage(original0, 0, 0, w0, h0, 0, 0, original0.getWidth(null), original.getHeight(null), null);

    // Drawing is finished, no need for canvas anymore
    g2d.dispose();

    // Done!
    return scaled;
}
```

However, it's probably better to resize the external icon files instead, and not give the extra work to your application.